# Add customers order comment to 'Order Confirmation' transaction email

Tags: magento-1.9, email-templates, sales, transactional-mail

When the customer places an order on the frontend they have the ability to add a comment to their order. What i would like to do is add this comment to the transaction email 'Order Confirmation' I checked in the listed variables but i can't seem to see a variable that would print this information, however in the same template this is used:

```
{{var order.getEmailCustomerNote():escape|nl2br}}
```

Is this the order comment? cause if it is, it is not displaying for me. How would i go about adding the customers order comment to this template or will i need to write a custom module?

does this functionality/variable already exist to display the order comment?

Thanks